# Consolidating my proof for the merge step of mergesort

Tags: correctness-proof, induction, check-my-answer

I've been spending time strengthening my ability to conduct inductive proofs and made one for the mergesort algorithm - specifically the merge part, as the entirety of the algorithm is comparatively trivial with an assumption that merge functions properly. I would like another pair of eyes on my proof to know if my arguments and assumptions are valid - it would be really helpful as I'm putting things together to know if I'm on the right track.

**Proof:** Let A[0...n] be the input array, and let $m$ be an integer such that the resulting arrays A[0...m] and A[m + 1...n] are sorted. These two arrays will be referred to as $A_i$ and $A_j$ - a reference to the head of each array, which is the smallest value that has not yet been processed. Our output array will be referred to as $B$; this is the array into which min($A_i \cup A_j$) will be added upon processing. The proof will be by induction on *M*, the number of elements that remain not merged.

First, we observe that min($A_i \cup A_j$) is necessarily the minimum element in the input array A: both $A_i$ and $A_j$ are sorted and comprise the entirety of $A$. Thus:

$$
A[i] \leq A[l], \forall l \in \{i + 1, ... m\}
$$

and

$$
A[j] \leq A[l], \forall l \in \{j + 1, ... n\}
$$

Observe the base case, which is $M$ = 0; this means that $A_i$ and $A_j$ are both empty. All processable elements have been processed, and there is no more merging left to do. Otherwise, there are four cases to consider for the $k$th iteration of the merge loop.

In the case that $M = 1$, there are two possible scenarios for $A_i$ and $A_j$:

- $A_i$ is populated and $A_j$ is empty: in this case, min($A_i \cup A_j$) = $A[i]$.
- $A_i$ is empty and $A_j$ is populated: in this case, min($A_i \cup A_j$) = $A[j]$.

In the case that $M \geq 2$, the minimum element is reliant on whether $A[i] < A[j]$ or $A[i] \geq A[j]$.

- In the case that $A[i] < A[j]$, min($A_i \cup A_j$) = $A[i]$.
- In the case that $A[i] \geq A[j]$, min($A_i \cup A_j$) = $A[j]$.

In all cases outside the base case, min($A_i \cup A_j$) - which we know to be the minimum element in $A$ - is identified and assigned to B[k] in the $k$th iteration. In the cases that min($A_i \cup A_j$) = $A[i]$, the principle of induction implies that the last n - k iterations of the merge loop will correctly merge $A[i+1...m]$ and $A[j...n]$ into $B[k+1...n]$. Alternatively, in the cases that min($A_i \cup A_j$) = $A[j]$, the principle of induction implies that the last n - k iterations of the merge loop will correctly merge $A[i...m]$ and $A[j+1...n]$ into $B[k+1...n]$.

---

This isn't the most formal proof, but I feel as if something is lacking in my logic outside of that; intuitively it makes sense to me, but I'm not sure if my statements are strong enough to constitute a definitive proof. I would like to know if there is anything I stated that is refutable or otherwise illegitimate in a way that invalidates my work. Particularly I would like to know if any of my language is redundant, and things I can add/take out to make this and future proofs more concise.